# Proof that $\lim{\frac{ln(n)}{n^3}} = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How to proof dat $\lim{\frac{ln(n)}{n^3}} = 0$ by the definition of the limit(of sequence)

Comment: $n\geq \ln n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof with the definition of limit. The general definition is

$$\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\,\exists N \in {\Bbb N}:\,if\,n \geqslant N\,then\,\left| {f(n) - L} \right| < \varepsilon $$

In your case, we must prove that

$$\forall \varepsilon  > 0,\,\exists N \in {\Bbb N}:\,if\,n \geqslant N\,then\,\left| {\frac{{\ln (n)}}{{{n^3}}}} \right| < \varepsilon $$

Consider the following

$$\left| {\frac{{\ln (n)}}{{{n^3}}}} \right| < \left| {\frac{n}{{{n^3}}}} \right| = \frac{1}{{{n^2}}} \leqslant \frac{1}{n}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left| {\frac{{\ln (n)}}{{{n^3}}}} \right| < \frac{1}{n}$$

Now if we choose $N$ such that

$$N \geqslant \frac{1}{\varepsilon }$$

we have

$$n \geqslant N \geqslant \frac{1}{\varepsilon }\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{n} \leqslant \varepsilon \,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left| {\frac{{\ln (n)}}{{{n^3}}}} \right| < \varepsilon \,$$

and hence the limit exists and is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, you can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ln(n)}{n^3}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\frac{d}{dn}ln(n)}{\frac{d}{dn}n^3}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{3n^2}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{3n^3}}\\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: are you sure this answers the question? I suspect the OP is interested in an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof since he or she mentioned the definition of limit in the question...